# How to style ant-design bar chart hover state?

Tags: plot, antdv

I can't change the color shown behind the bar with hover state on a plot ant-design chart ( I think that by default it is some sort of light blue )

I can't find the way to style it. The documentation is not helpful.

I have tried using onEvent when editing the ColumnConfig property:

```
onEvent: (column, event) => {
    if (event.type === 'mousemove') {
        column.options = {
            ...column.options,
            state: {
                ...column.options.state,
                active: {
                    ...column.options.state?.active,
                    style: {
                        ...column.options?.state?.active?.style,
                        fill: '#ff000',
                    },
                },
            },
        };
}
```

also tried editing according to the style:

```
state: {
    active: {
        style: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            stroke: '#ff000',
        },
    },  
},
```

but without success.
Can someone help me here, please?